# YUI compressor: Found an undeclared symbol

Tags: javascript, yui-compressor

I have a collection of Javascript files that together constitute a system. Different parts of the system are in different (global) namespaces (e.g., NSA, NSB, etc.) and those namespaces may be objects, e.g.

```
 NSA = { 
    ... lots of stuff ...
 }
```

Now, in my various modules, I may have code such as:

```
NSA.method();
```

My code JSLints clean because I declare these namespaced objects in a comment at the top of the file:

```
/*global dNSA NSB NSC */
```

When I run YUI Compressor (v 2.4.2) on these files with the -v (verbose) switch, it emits warnings about the referenced namespaced objects, such as:

```
Found an undeclared symbol: $
```

and that's for using $ for jQuery!

What can I do to define these variables so that YUI Compressor doesn't emit the warning, yet whatever I add can't cause a change to the object.

Comment: Ahh - seems this is a desired capability not yet provided. A ticket  exists: http://yuilibrary.com/projects/builder/ticket/21

Comment: I too am faced with the same issue.

Comment: Make sure you use an up-to-date problem. I had this issues until I changed to version 1.3.1.2

Answer (score 2):

The YUI library doesn't recognize Jquery, so it "thinks" its an error.  Seems like it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: This is not a specific issue with jQuery, but with any global value that I use in different files that are all loaded into the same application. JSLint provides a mechanism for telling it that some global is defined outside the current file. I was hoping that YUIC would provide similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
var $ = window.$;
```

to your code.

Comment: I tried this, but alas it causes a critical failure under I.E., which does not preserve the value of $. I can't imagine why not.